# Hot to do t.test on a long format data frame using grouping?

Tags: r

I had a break from R and I feel lost. I would like to calculate  t.test on the data of two groups and first i had it in long format

```
 > head(Book182)
 X35S.GFP.1  X35S.GFP.2 X35S.GFP.3   X35S.GFP.4       N85.GFP.1     N85.GFP.2 N85.GFP.3
 sp|P42212|GFP_AEQVI;smGFP          0         0.0          0           0.00  27209530   7785643   8443706
 sp|P42212|GFP_AEQVI        550434415 327284999.6  415328430 397967316.00         0         0         0
  AT5G14490.1                        0         0.0          0         0.00   9773408   6892342   8105905
  AT2G43680.1                  2660723   3525126.9    1227979   2244287.03         0         0         0
 AT2G39040.1                  3203949   2872219.1    2295579   2415679.17         0         0         0
  AT3G16430.1                        0    165655.7     187634     34859.24         0         0         0
                      N85.GFP.4
 sp|P42212|GFP_AEQVI;smGFP   2147864
 sp|P42212|GFP_AEQVI               0
 AT5G14490.1                 5876666
  AT2G43680.1                       0
  AT2G39040.1                       0
  AT3G16430.1                       0
```

but i thourght it will be asier to transform in to long

```
 head(Book18_melt)
              Accession   variable     value   X1  X2 X3
1 sp|P42212|GFP_AEQVI;smGFP X35S.GFP.1        NA X35S GFP  1
2       sp|P42212|GFP_AEQVI X35S.GFP.1 550434415 X35S GFP  1
3               AT5G14490.1 X35S.GFP.1        NA X35S GFP  1
4               AT2G43680.1 X35S.GFP.1   2660723 X35S GFP  1
5               AT2G39040.1 X35S.GFP.1   3203949 X35S GFP  1
6               AT3G16430.1 X35S.GFP.1         0 X35S GFP  1
```

I would liketo find differences between that samples that have "35S..." to the ones "85..." so I split the variable column by ".". I want to grou them by "Accession", next I want the two groups to be formed for each accession (35S vs 85) compare them save it as new table. but then i apply by code I keep getting one pvslaue for all my accessions... impossible

```
data.faramea<- Book18_melt %>%
group_by(Accession) %>%
do(broom::tidy(t.test(value ~ X1, Book18_melt, var.equal=TRUE))) %>%
ungroup
```

I think a t some point I lost it, the groups are created by Accession, because the outcome table has correct number of rown but because the numbers are identical there is something wrong with the broom:tidy and the code... help please help

Comment: You can create (`mutate`) a logical variable with `grepl("35S", X1)` and then run a `t.test(value ~ logiX1, etc)`.

Comment: yyy sorry could you please put it in a context of my code, I need to do grepl("35S", Book18$X1) and  grepl("85", Book18$X1) and data.faramea<- Book18_melt %>%
group_by(Accession) %>%
do(broom::tidy(t.test(value ~ X1, Book18_melt, var.equal=TRUE))) %>%
ungroup

Comment: Your data only has `"35S"` values. Can you subset the long df with some of those but also with some of the other rows and post the output of `dput(Book18_melt_subset)` in the question, please?